# MDG Technology custom toolboxes not showing with custom diagrams

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have created a MDG Technology in Sparx' Enterprise Architect version 12.1

The UML extensions  used to create custom element and relationships types works fine.

The custom toolboxes containing those custom elements and relationships as defined in a  work fine too when listing all tools.

The custom diagrams as defined in  are also available in the MDG Technology and can be used.

[image: Diagram Profile]
[image: Toolboxes]
And finally...
[image: Process Toolbox]
However, the custom toolbox assigned to each custom diagram does not open. They can be viewed and used by pinning them to the toolbox window, but this does not show only the toolbox relevant to the diagram.

I have followed the documentation and a colleague's successful attempt with no success.

Is there some trick or deep setting that might be stopping my MDG Technology from opening a custom toolbox for a custom diagram?

Comment: can you put your diagram profile?

Comment: Without the (demo) MDG there is little chance to help you. There are too many possible error sources.

Comment: I understand what you say @ThomasKilian... worth a shot though.

Comment: Make sure your toolbox profiles name are actually right, the name of the profile is set when you generate the profile file, its not the name of your toolbox diagram

Comment: So when I Save As Profile... the filename should be something like TSA Process Tools.xml? I had been doing Save As Profile on the package containing all the toolboxes. I will try that.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasKilian that it will be difficult to help you unless you post a screenshot of each step when you generate the technology file

Comment: What you can do, open the xml file of your technology and look for the definition of your diagram profiles, they should be at the end of your stereotypes, make sure the value of their toolbox property is the same as the name of the toolbox profiles defined a little bit lower

Comment: @WorkingMatt "I had been doing Save As Profile on the package containing all the toolboxes" Ah no, I think you need to save each diagram containing your toolboxes as a UML profile separately

Comment: Fixed! You genius @Mart10, please add it as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP mentionned in the comments, he was saving the whole package of his toolboxes as profile. This is wrong, you need to save all toolbox diagrams separately as a profile.

---

If you have problems with your technology, you can always open its XML file and make sure the expected profiles and their values are there